# Input field behaves different from different pages with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile

I have one page that links to another. On the second page I have a form input text field that does not work when coming from the first page. However, when surfing directly to the second page the form works perfectly. This is my code on my first page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div style=" text-align:center">
                <img style="width: 300px; height: 43px" src="http://www.jimand.se/explore/images/logoblue.png" />
            </div>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    Uppdrag
                </li>
                <li data-theme="d">
                    <a href="task1.html" data-transition="slide">
                        1
                    </a>
                </li>
```

This is my code on my second page (task1.html):

```
<div data-role="content"> 
<p>Ange l&ouml;senord</p>
<form id="login" action="" method="">
    <input name="pwtext" id="pwtext" placeholder="" value="" type="text" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" value="Klicka h&auml;r" id="sendbtn" name="sendbtn" />
</form>
```

My document.ready on my second page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#login").submit(function() {
                var emptyFields = $(":input.required").filter(function() {
                return !$.trim(this.value).length;
            });

            if(emptyFields.length) {
                $("#pwtext").css("background-color", "#ffff76");
                $("#pwtext").attr("placeholder", "Passeword required!");
            return false;
            }
            if ($('#pwtext').val() != 'llab') {
                $("#pwtext").css("background-color", "#ffff76");
                $("#pwtext").attr("placeholder", "Passeword required!");
                return false;
            }
            if ($('#pwtext').val() == 'llab') {
                $.mobile.changePage("#page2", "slideup");
                return false;
             }
            });

        });
```

this all could be tested here:
http://jimand.se/explore/start.html
pw: llab to try my form

Comment: _“ a form input text field that does not work”_ – that’s not a comprehensible error description.

Comment: Sorry but nothing happens when I click the submit button. The real scenario would change page.